# How to show image in div on hover with jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css, hover

I have list of features and I need to show image on hover over the `div` with icon and header (`.top-wrapper` class in code). Now I have some jquery code, but it works on all of the elements on hover, I need it to work separately on each of the elements.

HTML:

```
<ul class="row features-list justify-content-center justify-content-md-between justify-content-lg-center">
            <li class="col-xl-3">
                <img src="images/features-card-img.png" alt="Bottle">
                <div class="d-flex flex-column bottle-text-wrapper arrow-up text-left mx-auto">
                    <h3 class="features-item-header bottle-header">Redesigning With Personality</h3>
                    <span class="bottle-small-text ml-auto">in <span class="yellow-text">web design</span></span>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="col-10 col-sm-6 col-md-5 col-lg-4 col-xl-3 feature-item">
                <div class="feature-top" id="feature-top-dev">
                    <div class="top-wrapper">
                    <i class="fa fa-desktop" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <h3 class="features-item-header">Web Development</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="hover-content">
                        <img src="images/features-card-img.png" alt="Bottle">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="feature-bottom mx-auto">
                    <p class="features-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
                        consectetur.</p>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="col-10 col-sm-6 col-md-5 col-lg-4 col-xl-3 feature-item">
                <div class="feature-top" id="feature-top-design">
                    <div class="top-wrapper">
                    <i class="fa fa-th" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <h3 class="features-item-header">Web Design</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="hover-content">
                        <img src="images/features-card-img.png" alt="Bottle">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="feature-bottom mx-auto">
                    <p class="features-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
                        consectetur.</p>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="col-10 col-sm-6 col-md-5 col-lg-4 col-xl-3 feature-item">
                <div class="feature-top" id="feature-top-graph-des">
                    <div class="top-wrapper">
                    <i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <h3 class="features-item-header">Graphic Design</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="hover-content">
                        <img src="images/features-card-img.png" alt="Bottle">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="feature-bottom mx-auto">
                    <p class="features-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
                        consectetur.</p>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

jquery:

```
 $('#feature-top-dev').hover(
        function() {
            $('.top-wrapper').addClass('d-none');
            $('.feature-top').css({'padding': '0', 'background-color': '#f5f5f5'});
            $('.hover-content').fadeIn('slow');
        },function() {
            $('.top-wrapper').removeClass('d-none');
            $('.feature-top').css({'padding': '20px 0', 'background-color': '#ffea00'});
            $('.hover-content').fadeOut('slow');
        }
    );
```

Screenshot how it looks:
[image]

**On hover over the div with yellow background it need to be changed to image.**

Comment: don`t use id use class name.  Id must be unique. If you use id you gets only first element

Comment: `id`need to be unique per element , so use `class`

Comment: my code works now, but when I hover on "Web Development" `div` image appears on all of the `div's` with yellow background. But I need to show image only on "Web Development" `div` if I hover over it and same with other `div's` with yellow background.

Answer (score 0):

You should put your img with css attributes like

```
img.hover {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
}
```

so when you hover your element, you fadeToggle() your image and fadeToggle() it back when the mouse leaves maybe